# <p:focus does not work when it is in a p:tabView

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, focus

`<P:focus` tag works fine in normal forms but when the form is in the second tab of a `p:tabView` it does not work.

What is the solution the set the focus of the first input of the form when the tab is selected?

Comment: how about updating second tab`<p:ajax event="tabChange" update=":secondTabID"/>` or using jquery focus with tab client side api , something like this `onTabChange="jQuery('#someForm\\:someTab\\:someInput').focus();"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your hint I solve the problem this way:

```
onTabShow="tabShowHandler()"
```

**And the javascript part:**

```
function tabShowHandler() {
   var inputUsername = $('#tabView\\:frmRegister\\:username');
   inputUsername.focus();
}
```